# Filter array of strings that are not starting with an alphabet

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, filter

I want to filter example array given in below snippet when some button is clicked
I want to get an expected output as it is not starting with an alphabet

I tried

```
const example = ["test", 'xyz', '1 test', 'ramu']
example.filter(e => !e.startsWith('t'))
```

Expected Output: `['1 test']`

Comment: If you want to filter only the ones starting with a non-alphabet letter then why are you trying like `e.startsWith('t')`?

Answer (score 2):

You could check with a regular expression.

```js
var array = ["test", 'xyz', '1 test', 'ramu'],
    result = array.filter(s => /^[^a-z]/i.test(s));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code:

```js
t =["test", 'xyz', '1 test', 'ramu']
function check(i) {
    return ((i >= 'a' && i <= 'z') || (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z'));
}

t.filter(e => !check(e.charAt(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expression(Regex).

```js
var strings = ["test", 'xyz', '1 test', 'ramu'];
var regex = /[A-Za-z]/; // Regex for Alphabets

var filteredStrings = strings.filter((string) => regex.test(string[0])); // Filtering strings not starting with alphabets

console.log(filteredStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use charCodeAt here

```
let arr =["test", 'xyz', '1 test', 'ramu'];

let ans = arr.filter(x=> {
    let temp = x.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
    console.log(temp);
    if(temp<=65 || temp>=91) {
        return x;
    }
});

console.log(ans);
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41bsdf0h/)